# Woocommerce update stock quantity using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, woocommerce

I cannot find the meta key for the stock quantity in Woocommerce. What would be the best way to update the stock quantity in Woocommerce using MYSQL?

Comment: the meta key is `_stock` and is locate on `wp_postmeta` table…

Comment: be aware updating stock directly might cause confusing on your front end due transit or cash instead build small script to update the stock using wc_update_product_stock function

Comment: Try this  `UPDATE wp_postmeta set meta_value = 'instock' WHERE meta_key = '_stock_status' AND meta_value = 'outofstock'`   ... to update quantity, use this: `UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = 99 WHERE meta_key = '_stock' AND meta_value IS NULL`

Answer (score 1):

it's more secure you use the PHP functions. But if you want to update using sql, you can try this:

**Checking stock**

```
SELECT * FROM olenka.wp_postmeta where meta_key = '_stock';
```

**Checking stock status:**

```
SELECT post_id AS id, meta_value AS stockstatus FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_stock_status'
```

**Set manage stock true:**

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = 'yes' WHERE meta_key = '_manage_stock'
```

**Set the 'instock' flag:**

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta set meta_value = 'instock' WHERE meta_key = '_stock_status' AND meta_value = 'outofstock'
```

**Update the stock**

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = 99 WHERE meta_key = '_stock' AND meta_value IS NULL;
```

OR

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = 99 WHERE meta_key = '_stock' AND meta_value > 0;
```